# how can get data from api to child combobox in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i can't move my code to child component so how can i solve this problem. so that i can use my api data to my combobox

```
async getData() {
const PROXY_URL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const URL = 'my-api';
const res = await axios({
  method: 'post', // i get data from post response
  url: PROXY_URL+URL, 
  data: {
    id_user : this.props.user.id_user
  }
})

const {data} = await res;
this.setState({ user : data.data})
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getData()
  }
```

and i send my state to my combobox in child component

```
      <ComboBox
        name="pic"
        label="Default PIC"
        placeholder=""
        refs={register({ required: true })}
        error={errors.PIC}
        message=""
        labelFontWeight="400"
        datas={this.state.user}
      ></ComboBox>
```

combobox code :
right now I just want to be able to console my index data

```
let ComboBox = props => {
useEffect(() => {
for (let i = 0; i < props.datas.length; i++) {
  console.log(i) //this can use if using hard props or manual data
  props.datas[i].selected = false;


  props.datas[i].show = true;
}
setDatas(props.datas);


document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  try {
    if (!refDivComboBox.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  } catch (error) {}
});

unSelectedComboBox();
}, []);
export default ComboBox;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand the problem, could you explain it a bit further? Are you getting what you want in the `datas` prop in the `ComboBox` component?

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac befoer i used api my combobox like this `<ComboBox datas = {name : "test", value : "test"}/>`. And now i should get my data from api but i don't know why my code did'n works

Comment: Did you try doing `console.log(this.state.user)` before you send it to the ComboBox? Maybe the data is invalid, or not set?

Comment: useeffect like ComponentDidMount right? but my api data need 2 second to get my data. so how my useeffect use after i get my api data? just can read in console maybe can help me

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac sure i try console.log(this.state.user)

Comment: I just added a potential answer, I think I see the mistake now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the props.datas dependency in your ComboBox component.

```
let ComboBox = props => {
useEffect(() => {
for (let i = 0; i < props.datas.length; i++) {
  console.log(i) //this can use if using hard props or manual data
  props.datas[i].selected = false;


  props.datas[i].show = true;
}
setDatas(props.datas);


document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  try {
    if (!refDivComboBox.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  } catch (error) {}
});

unSelectedComboBox();
}, [props.datas]); // THIS IS THE DEPENDENCY ARRAY, try adding props.datas here
export default ComboBox;
```

Here is a brief explanation of `useEffect`.

Used as `componentDidMount()`:

```
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

Used as `componentDidUpdate()` (triggers after `props.something` changes):

```
useEffect(() => {}, [props.something])
```

Used as `componenWillUnmount()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => { //Unmount }
}, [])
```

This, of course, is a really simple explanation, and this can be used much better when properly learned. Take a look at some tutorials utilizing `useState`, try to find in particular migrations from `this.state` to `useState` - those might help you wrap your head around `useState`

Comment: thanks Mr. it's 100% works. how stupid i'm forgot the little things

Comment: `useState` confuses some of very experienced programmers I know, nothing about your mistake was stupid, it is really useful util once you master it, and asking questions about it is a good way to master it :)

Comment: I just recognize using React, i hope u can help me on another occasion, thank you for this very useful knowledge. and forgive if my English is not right because I'm still in learning too